# Take right string after ^ in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some data in SQL Server:

```
test1^test2^test3^test4  
test5  
test6^test7  
null
```

Desired output:

```
test4
test5
test7
null
```

Comment: Surprised nobody said this, the absolute best solution would be to stop storing delimited data like this. It violates 1NF and is a pain to work with. Of course we don't have that option but it would be the best if it is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `right()` with `charindex()` & `reverse()`:

```
select *, right(col, charindex('^', reverse(col) + '^')-1)
from ( values ('test1^test2^test3^test4'), ('test5'), ('test6^test7'), (null)  
     ) t(col);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4b72a6fc73a62769b7034f73d072cc4)

Comment: @Larnu. . .  Sorry you have to re-look.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti. . .  You also re-look.

Comment: @YogeshSharma You also re-look  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b51ba11b7b3e347489ec913616aec939

Comment: My original comment is incorrect, however, this does run on the assumption all the values are the same length. That is a poor assumption (in my opinion) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=837041486e735dbf112c580b39639540). This is effectively getting the position of the **first** `^` and then *assuming* the **last** value will be the same length.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti. . .  In that case `reverse()` would do the trick.

Comment: I saw your correction.  Perhaps next time two established members of the community raise a concern, you won't be so defensive.

Comment: Yogesh is quite establish himself, in fairness. We all make mistakes (and I made a poor/incorrect assumption myself when I made the original comment). `REVERSE`, however, does indeed fix the problem. :)

Comment: @Larnu Agreed.  That's why I didn't expect that response

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to split the value, using [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) and then take the "last" one (by ordering high to low). This method uses `TOP 1 WITH TIES` *I used this method as order seems to be irrelevant here*:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT Col
    FROM (VALUES('test1^test2^test3^test4'),
                ('test5'),
                ('test6^test7'),
                ('test9^test10'),
                (null)) V(col))
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       V.Col,
       DS.item
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedsplit8k_LEAD(V.Col,'^') DS
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.Col ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber DESC);
```

This avoids what can be an expensive `REVERSE`.

Answer (score 0):

using charindex and reverse:

I left all the functions in there so you could see the process.

```
declare @t table (test varchar(100))

insert into @t
values
('test1^test2^test3^test4')
,('test5')
,('test6^test7')  
,(null  )

select test
    ,revTest
    ,charInd
    ,reverse(left(revTest,case when charind = 0 then len(revTest) else charInd-1 end))
from @t t
cross apply (select reverse(rtrim(ltrim(test)))) a(revTest)
cross apply (select CHARINDEX('^',revTest)) b(charInd)
```

Results:

```
**test                  revTest                 charInd (Result)**
test1^test2^test3^test4 4tset^3tset^2tset^1tset 6       test4
test5                   5tset                   0       test5
test6^test7             7tset^6tset             6       test7
NULL                    NULL                    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
declare 
@col varchar(500), @reveCol varchar(500);
set @col='test133^test2^test3^test4';
set @reveCol=reverse(@col)


Select charindex('^', @revecol )
select right( @col ,charindex('^', @revecol )-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on **SQL Server 2016+**

Also assuming this schema and data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data;
CREATE TABLE #Data(StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO #Data(StringValue)VALUES
    ('test1^test2^test3^test4')
    ,('test5')
    ,('test6^test7')
    ,(NULL)
;
```

**The query:**

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '["' + REPLACE(COALESCE(d.StringValue,''),'^','","') + '"]' AS [JSONValue]
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY d.StringValue) AS [ID]
    FROM #Data d
)
SELECT NULLIF(a.value,'') AS [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT j.value,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY j.[key] DESC) AS [rn] 
    FROM cte AS c
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.JSONValue) j
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on **SQL Server 2017+**

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN d.StringValue LIKE '%'+s.value THEN s.[value] ELSE NULL END) AS [Result]
FROM ( VALUES
     ('test1^test2^test3^test4')
    ,('test5')
    ,('test6^test7')
    ,(NULL)
) d(StringValue)
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COALESCE(d.StringValue,''),'^') s
GROUP BY d.StringValue
;
```